# Why is ROC and DET plotting the same thing i.e. a trade off between FAR and FRR in bob.measure?

Tags: roc

ROC https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/bob.measure/v2.4.1/guide.html#roc

and

DET https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/bob.measure/v2.4.1/guide.html#det

are plotting the same thing that is a trade off between FAR and FRR

While ROC is a trade-off between the FAR and TAR. DET is correct!

I was expecting ROC to plot a trade off between TAR and FAR

See a reference in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_det.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-det-py